# Collect form variables in a function and send them as a single variable

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables, submit

I have a form with check boxes. When the form is submitted, I want to collect all the checked values form the check boxes in a single variable and send it to a different page along with another variable. Please help.

```
<form name="form1" method="get" onsubmit="sendThis()">
<input type=checkbox name="checkbux" value=<from database/>"
<input type=checkbox name="checkbux" value=<from database/>"
<input type=checkbox name="checkbux" value=<from database/>"
<input type=checkbox name="checkbux" value=<from database/>"
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

function sendThis()
{
var tableName = "<?= $p ?>"; //obtaining the value from another php file
var allVar = a,c,d; //checked values from check boxes
window.location = 'http://localhost/fourthpage.php?q=' + allVar + '&p=' + tableName'
}
```

Comment: Doesn't PHP automatically do this with `$_GET`?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy,  I want to send it q=a,c,d (not checkbux=a&checkbux=c&checkbux=d and split in PHP) so that I can execute query on database like 'select $q from $p'. I cooked something, I will posted in the answer section.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this without doing the javascript function. Like this

```
<form name="form1" action="/fourthpage.php" method="get">
<input type=checkbox name="q" value=<from database/>
<input type=checkbox name="q" value=<from database/>
<input type=checkbox name="q" value=<from database/>
<input type=checkbox name="q" value=<from database/>
<input type=hidden name="p" value="<?= $p ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Al, I will try this, especially hidden type assigning PHP variable gonna come in handy. I also cooked something, I will posted in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Send it inside an array, 
for example:

```
<input type=checkbox name="checkbux[]" value=<from database/>"
<input type=checkbox name="checkbux[]" value=<from database/>"
<input type=checkbox name="checkbux[]" value=<from database/>"
```

Comment: Thanks eve, I will try this. I also cooked something, I will posted in the answer section.